# Why would a username appear twice with Sharing and Permissions in a folder?

Tags: finder, permission

I've done some light Google-ing, and this is a about an explanation and a request for help.

This is a folder which looks normal enough,

[image]

but sometimes the black icon representing a single user (the one with the circle) appears twice from what I've heard.

I renamed my user account johndoe to johndoe-old and moved files across to the new johndoe account, changed permissions as needed, but sometimes the user appeared twice (johndoe).

I had to do a lot of sudo chmod -R -N to fix ACL's.

Why would the black icon with the user head symbol appear twice if only one user exists on the machine?

Comment: If you renamed the account, there should be nothing to move. Did you check the 'new' account is still 501, or is it now 502?

Comment: @Tetsujin: The new account is a 502, the now-deleted old account was 501. I renamed 501 to johndoe-old and 502 is now johndoe (original username, real name not here for privacy) as per echo $UID.

Comment: So in effect you have 2 admin accounts, rather than one renamed - that's the source of your issue. I think you're going to have to `chown` them, but it's really not my strong suit. See https://osxdaily.com/2013/04/23/change-file-ownership-mac-os-x/ which I'm not sure I could tuen into an answer.